# dist(x,Z)? , Z is span , x(t)=|t|

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

$Z=$span(sint,cost,sin2t) , x(t)=|t|

how to find $dist(x,Z)$ in $L_2(-\pi,\pi)$

dist(x,Z)= $inf ||x-z||$ where $z\in Z$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

1. Use the given basis to find an orthonormal basis for $Z$ : Let $\{v_1, v_2, v_3\}$ be that basis.
2. Define $P: L_2(-\pi,\pi) \to Z$ be the orthogonal projection
   $$
   P(x) = \sum_{i=1}^3 \langle x,v_i\rangle v_i
   $$
   Then prove that
   $$
   d(x,Z) = \|(I-P)(x)\|
   $$
   which, for a given function $x$, one can explicitly compute (in principle)